# Why is 'on' separated with 'to' in this sentence?

Tags: prepositions

Sentence:

> incautiously held it upright, whereupon the tobacco fell out **ON TO** the floor
>   *[(George Orwell, 1984. Page #8)](http://www.planetebook.com/ebooks/1984.pdf)*

Additional information:

> I know that when we describe some movement *(e.g. into the room, onto the bus, onto the shelf, onto the bed)* we always should use preposition of movement *(into, onto etc)*

Question:

> Why is 'on' separated with 'to' in the sentence

Comment: It should be: fell out onto the floor. The editor might have missed it. And it's not JOHN Orwell, it's: ***George Orwell", for the book called 1984.

Comment: Mistakes happen, this looks nothing more than that. Have you seen any other example like that in a more... "professional" context which would indicate that it's not a typo?

Comment: @ Korvin there's the only case like this that I've ever met

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: it's fine either way: *onto* or *on to*.

This [usage note by Oxford Dictionaries](https://web.archive.org/web/20220825044652/https://www.lexico.com/grammar/onto-or-on-to) should clarify it.

> #### ‘Onto’ or ‘on to’?

> The preposition **onto** meaning ‘to a position on the surface of’ has been widely written as one word (instead of **on to**) since the early 18th century, as in the following sentences:

> *He threw his plate **onto** the floor.*
> *The band climbed **onto** the stage.*

> Nevertheless, some people still don’t accept it as part of standard British English (unlike *into*) and it’s best to use the two-word form in formal writing.

> In US English, **onto** is more or less the standard form: it seems likely that this will eventually become the case in British English too. [...]